# Problems calling a DLL library from C# on iOS because of encoding

Tags: c#, dll, character-encoding, xamarin.ios, dllimport

I have special problem. I use Xamarin.iOS and try to call a function of a DLL library. The original function is defined as

```
LUALIB_API int luaL_loadbuffer (lua_State *L, 
                                const char *buff, 
                                size_t size,
                                const char *name)
```

and imported in C# as

```
[CLSCompliant (false)]
[DllImport(LIBNAME,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int luaL_loadbuffer(IntPtr luaState, 
                                         string buff, 
                                         uint size, 
                                         string name);
```

If you can see, the library is Lua 5.1, the C# side is KeraLua, a wrapper for the library. From Lua you could call this function with a string in buff, like "a=2", which than is compiled to binary code for Lua. But you can also call this function with a binary chunk (precompiled chunk) in buff. Than buff is a byte array.

Now my problem is, that strings work perfect. But binary chunks are converted wrong. I had to convert the byte array into a string, which is in C# encoded in UTF-16. If I than call the function, this "string" is converted from UTF-16 to UTF-8. This is no problem, when buff contains text, but with binary data, the result is wrong.

An example: an integer  in the binary data, which looks in the byte array as D6 21 00 00, converted to string with

```
StringBuilder s = new StringBuilder();
foreach (byte b in byteArray)
  s.Append((char)b);
```

results in D6 21 00 00. Than call the function and get in the library C3 96 21 00 00, which is obviously wrong. This is because UTF-16 D6 is in UTF-8 C3 96 and is changed while calling the function.

Coming to end, how should I define/call the function, so that this conversion didn't happen? Using Encoding.Ansi or Encoding.ASCII didn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using .NET you can create **two** managed methods (either overloads or using different names by changing the `DllImport` attribute properties) that points to the **same** native function.

The first would use a `string` parameter. That's what you already have.

The second would use a `byte[]` parameter. That would ensure the data is not decoded (and modified) before going to native. Something like:

```
[DllImport(LIBNAME,CallingConvention=CallingConvention.Cdecl)]
public static extern int luaL_loadbuffer(IntPtr luaState, 
                                     byte[] buff, 
                                     uint size, 
                                     string name);
```

Comment: Fantastic! Such a easy thing and couldn't get it for a long time.

Thank you very much!